# Ошибка при удалении ZIP после работы с ним

Tags: c#, zip

Использую библиотеку DotNetZip.dll для работы с ZIP.

```
ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(tempFile); 
foreach (string err in converter.Errors)
{
}
zip=null;
```

Поcле пытаюсь удалить архив и получаю исключение:

> The process cannot access the file 'MyZip.zip' because it is being used by another process

Можете объяснить почему процесс не освобождает архив и как правильно это делать?

Comment: После того как сделаете, то что планировали - вызовите на zip.Dispose()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) использовать `zip.Dispose();` в конце операций.

2) либо обернуть в оператор `using`:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(tempFile)) 
{
  foreach (string err in converter.Errors)
  {
  }
}
```